# How to force multiline in ConfirmationDialog item in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, text, dialog, multiline

I have a confirmation dialog with one entry being a bit too long to be display in a single line, so it gets cut in the middle:

[image: Screenshot of confirmation dialog with text too long for one line]

Nothing that I've tried has worked, I'm a bit out of ideas here.

Though there is one notable thing being that it *is* possible somehow: if I show the dialog, then increase the text size (from accessibility options) then at some point it will wrap around on multiple lines! And at this point if I keep the dialog open and I go back to a smaller text size, it will even stay on multiple lines, this being the result I would like initially. And of course if I close and reopen the dialog, it goes back to being single line and cut to fit

[image: Screenshot of confirmation dialog with large text from accessibility options, wrapping on multiple lines]

Tried setting height with `.frame(height:`, also using `.fixedSize(`, but didn't work

Here is a small snippet to reproduce

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ConfirmationDialogTest: View {
    @State private var showDialog = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Show dialog") {
                showDialog = true
            }
        }
        .confirmationDialog("Confirmation", isPresented: $showDialog) {
            Button("OK") {}
            Button("Very long text that will eventually be too long to be displayed on only one single line") {}
            Button("Delete", role: .destructive) {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use different initializer for the button? The one that asks you to provide custom label, for instance this one: [init(role:action:label:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/button/init(role:action:label:)). Presumably you could tell the inside text to be multi line 

Comment: You have to insert '\n' to the titleKey manually to add a new line, I suppose.

Comment: @ElTomato it seems it just cut the line where you insert ‘\n’ and the rest of the text won’t be visible

Comment: Okay.  I can have two lines, three lines and probably more, though.

Comment: @Suprafen I have also tried adding a '\n' inside the string and it does get cut at the newline, and the rest of the text isn't shown. How did you do it ?

Comment: I think this is a question for @ElTomato, since I was not able to make button behaves as you wanted to ‍♂️

Comment: @Suprafen oops yeah mb 

Comment: @ElTomato the comment above about the `\n` was for you

Comment: @Suprafen for information using the `init` with `label:` and trying to make the label multiline doesn't seem to work either